# Rendering dynamic rows from the input field in REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, filter

Im a newbie to React ,my question is very simple ,I have a form which has a input field which gets some input data and on Submit the form,the input data should render as a row  and delete button which can we delete the data if onClicked .I have implemented the rendering of the rows but there is doubt In deleting functionality.

the code for App.js file is ,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    names: [],
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = document.getElementById("namevalue").value;
    const obj = { id: Date.now(), value };
    this.setState({
      names: [obj, ...this.state.names],
    });
    document.getElementById("myform").reset();
    
   
    return;
  };

  renderTable() {
    return (
      this.state.names &&
      this.state.names.map((name) => {
        const { id, value } = name; //destructuring
        return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{value}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="button"
                value="Delete"
                onClick={this.deleteName(id)}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })
    );
  }

  deleteName = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    /* this.setState({
      names: this.setState.names.filter((name) => name.id !== id),
    });*/
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="myform">
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" id="namevalue" />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        {/* Table */}
        <br />
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Names</th>
              <th>Operation</th>
            </tr>
            {/* Render dynamic rows
             */}
            {this.renderTable()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see i have implemented the delete method but it throws error
[image: The browser output]

I want to delete the row on clicking the delete button but on clicking the button it throws error as,

[image: Error]

Comment: <input
                type="button"
                value="Delete"
                onClick={() =>deleteName(id)}
              />

Comment: Hi @KostyaTresko,thanks for your reply,will 'this' keyword will come in front of the method name as  onClick={(id) =>this.deleteName(id)}

Comment: Still I cant delete the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the onClick value should be a function reference, otherwise it would introduce a rendering loop.

```
onClick={() => this.deleteName(id)}
```

You can then implement the delete function by using array.splice function, as follows:

```
deleteName = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    const { names } = this.state;
    const index = names.findIndex(name => name.id === id);
    this.setState({
      names: [
        ...names.splice(index, 1),
      ]
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

For Class component always used like this,
onClick={() => this.deleteName(id)}

For Functional component
onClick = {deleteName(id)

Comment: Its ok but i cant use the filter option to delete the row and update the state,

    this.setState.names &&
      this.setState({
        names: this.setState.names.filter((name) => name.id !== id),
      });

Comment: this.setState({ names: this.state.names.filter((name) => name.id !== id) }); 
You have to use state inside setState, no the setState function again!

Comment: Hey @Veno ,You save my day ,thanks a lot, im a bit confused in clsas components,thanks  to Hooks

Answer (score 1):

````
export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    names:[]
  };

  
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = document.getElementById("namevalue").value;
    const obj = { id: Date.now(), value };
    this.setState({
      names: [obj, ...this.state.names],
    });
    document.getElementById("myform").reset();
    
   
    return;
  };

  deleteName = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
     this.setState({
      names: this.state.names.filter((name) => name.id !== id) //corrected here
    });
  };


  renderTable() {
    return (
      this.state.names &&
      this.state.names.map((name) => {
        const { id, value } = name; //destructuring
        return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{value}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="button"
                value="Delete"
                onClick={()=>this.deleteName(id)} //corrected here
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })
    );
  }

 

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="myform">
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" id="namevalue" />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        {/* Table */}
        <br />
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Names</th>
              <th>Operation</th>
            </tr>
            {/* Render dynamic rows
             */}
            {this.renderTable()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Hey Akshay,thanks for your kind reply,i have features to enhance in this project hope you'll help !